# Mocking OpenXML SDK SpreadsheetDocument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, openxml-sdk

I would like to use process described here: [Automated Testing OpenXML SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356503/automated-testing-openxml-sdk)
(also touched here: [Unit testing an application that talks to microsoft word via OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595108/unit-testing-an-application-that-talks-to-microsoft-word-via-openxml))

However, what does it take to mock the something like this?
I have made the following interface:

```
public interface IExcelDocument
{
    Row GetRow(uint rowIndex, SheetData sheetData);
    SharedStringTablePart GetSharedStringTablePart(SpreadsheetDocument excelDoc);
    WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(SpreadsheetDocument excelDoc, string sheetName);
    Cell InsertCellInWorksheet(string columnName, uint rowIndex, WorksheetPart worksheetPart);
    Row InsertRow(WorksheetPart worksheetPart);
    int InsertSharedStringItem(string text, SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart);
}
```

I would imagine mocking would look something like this:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Excel_GetWorkseetPartTest()
{
    Mock<IExcelDocument> mockExcelDocument = new Mock<IExcelDocument>();
    string sheetName = "sheet";
    var excelMock = mockExcelDocument.Object.GetWorksheetPart(MySpreadsheetDocument, sheetName);

    Assert.IsTrue(excelMock != null);
}
```

`GetWorksheetPart` method which I want to unit test and resides in the class which implements the interface `IExcelDocument` looks like this:

```
public WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(SpreadsheetDocument excelDoc, string sheetName)
{
    Sheet sheet = excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>()
        .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == sheetName);
    if (sheet == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            String.Format("No sheet named {0} found in spreadsheet {1}",
                sheetName, _filePath), "sheetName");
    }
    return (WorksheetPart)excelDoc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
}
```

I am not able to wrap around `MySpreadsheetDocument` because I would need to also implement the `SpreadsheetDocument.Open` method and not sure even if that is reasonable.

Here is how I call `GetWorksheetPart`:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument _excelDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(_filePath, true))
{
    IExcelDocument excelDoc = new ExcelDocument();
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = excelDoc.GetWorksheetPart(_excelDoc, sheetName);
}
```

Comment: Is your method under test in a class implementation of the interface? Your wording is a little confusing

Comment: if that is the case then you are confusing the concept of abstracting your dependencies for your unit test.

Comment: Ok, could you please give a small example on the particular case?

Comment: @Nkosi do you have some private contact which I could use to ask you one SO semi-related question?

Comment: What seems to be the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi no problem, just curiosity. Wanted to ask regards your profile and how does this go together with your professional career.. Could not find a private way to contact, thus commented here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the concept of abstracting your dependencies for your unit test.

given an example class

```
public class ExcelDocument {

    public WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(SpreadsheetDocument excelDoc, string sheetName)
    {
        Sheet sheet = excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>()
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == sheetName);
        if (sheet == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                String.Format("No sheet named {0} found in spreadsheet {1}",
                    sheetName, _filePath), "sheetName");
        }
        return (WorksheetPart)excelDoc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
    }
}
```

this method is dependent on external component `SpreadsheetDocument`

`SpreadsheetDocument` is what needs to be abstracted in this case.

Looking at the method under test, the method needs to be able to get a `Sheet` so your abstraction must provide that functionality. it also needs to be able to get `WorksheetPart`

from this the following interface can be derived

```
public ISpreadsheetDocument {    
    Sheet GetSheet(string name);
    WorksheetPart GetPartById(string id);
}
```

This changes the Method under test to this

```
public WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(ISpreadsheetDocument excelDoc, string sheetName)
{
    Sheet sheet = excelDoc.GetSheet(sheetName);
    if (sheet == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            String.Format("No sheet named {0} found in spreadsheet {1}",
                sheetName, _filePath), "sheetName");
    }
    return excelDoc.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
}
```

You can now mock/fack the excelDoc if needed for your unit tests and then your production implementation would wrap the external functionality.

```
public class SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper : ISpreadsheetDocument {
    private SpreadsheetDocument excelDoc;
    public SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper(SpreadsheetDocument excelDoc) {
        this.excelDock = excelDock;
    }

    public Sheet GetSheet(string name) {
        return excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>()
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == sheetName);
    }

    public WorksheetPart GetPartById(string id) {
        return (WorksheetPart)excelDoc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(id);
    }
}
```

So what you need to do is look at your `ExcelDocument` class, identify its dependencies and abstract those dependencies out into services that you can mock for unit testing.

Comment: Thanks Nkosi, well described. I am trying to mock now. I have created the example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KZSN5B. 
Could you please suggest on how would the unit test for the `GetWorksheetPart` look like?

Comment: Posted this as a new question. As this one is already answered. Thanks again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638048/mocking-openxml-with-moq