# Mocking OpenXML with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, openxml

How should I test the following `GetWorksheetPart` method:

```
public class ExcelDocument : IExcelDocument
{
    private readonly string _filePath;

    public ExcelDocument(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    public WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(ISpreadsheetDocument excelDoc, string sheetName)
    {
        Sheet sheet = excelDoc.GetSheet(sheetName);
        if (sheet == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                String.Format("No sheet named {0} found in spreadsheet {1}",
                    sheetName, _filePath), "sheetName");
        }
        return excelDoc.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
    }
}
```

Where `IExcelDocument` and wrapper's `SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper` interfaces are:

```
public interface IExcelDocument
{
    WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(ISpreadsheetDocument excelDoc, string sheetName);
}

public interface ISpreadsheetDocument
{
    Sheet GetSheet(string name);

    WorksheetPart GetPartById(string id);
}
```

Here is the wrapper itself.

```
public class SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper : ISpreadsheetDocument
{
    private SpreadsheetDocument excelDoc;

    public SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper(SpreadsheetDocument excelDoc)
    {
        this.excelDoc = excelDoc;
    }

    public Sheet GetSheet(string sheetName)
    {
        return excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>()
                   .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == sheetName);
    }

    public WorksheetPart GetPartById(string id)
    {
        return (WorksheetPart)excelDoc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(id);
    }
}
```

Finally, the test which I tried to implement for `GetWorksheetPart`. Issue with this is that I am not sure how to test this functionality. Idea is to get a `WorksheetPart` given the sheet name and the spreadsheet document.

```
public class Test
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class ExcelUpdateLogicTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void Excel_GetWorkseetPartTest()
        {
            Mock<ISpreadsheetDocument> mockSpreadhseet = new Mock<ISpreadsheetDocument>();
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
            string id = "1";
            sheet.Name = "sheet";
            sheet.Id = id;

            mockSpreadhseet.Setup(doc => doc.GetSheet("sheet")).Returns(sheet);

            mockSpreadhseet.Setup(doc => doc.GetPartById(id)).Returns(????);

            Mock<IExcelDocument> mockExcelDocument = new Mock<IExcelDocument>();
            WorksheetPart mockWorkseet = mockExcelDocument.Object
                .GetWorksheetPart(mockSpreadhseet.Object, "sheet");

            Assert.IsTrue(mockWorkseet.GetIdOfPart(mockWorkseet) == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the general OpenXML structure tree for Spreadsheets:

> ```
>                 Spreadsheet
>                       |         
>                  WorkbookPart    
>            /         |             \
>    Workbook WorkbookStylesPart WorksheetPart
>          |          |               |
>     Sheets     StyleSheet        Worksheet
>         |                        /        \       
>   (refers to               SheetData        Columns  
>    Worksheetparts)            |   
>                              Rows
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ExcelDocument` is the system under test then there is no need to mock `IExcelDocument`. You should mock/stub/fake the dependencies needed to test the SUT

Now I was able to get your test to pass like this...

```
public class Test {
    [TestClass()]
    public class ExcelUpdateLogicTests {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void Given_SheetName_ExcelDocument_Should_GetWorkseetPart() {
            //Arrange
            var stream = new MemoryStream();//Avoid having to use actual file on disk
            var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            // Add a WorkbookPart.
            WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            // Add a WorksheetPart.
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

            // Add a sheets list.
            Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

            // Append the new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
            string expectedId = workbookpart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);
            string sheetName = "mySheet";

            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() {
                Id = expectedId,
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = sheetName
            };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            var wrapper = new SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper(spreadsheetDocument);

            string fakeFilePath = "path";
            var sut = new ExcelDocument(fakeFilePath);

            //Act
            WorksheetPart result = sut.GetWorksheetPart(wrapper, sheetName);

            //Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            var actualId = workbookpart.GetIdOfPart(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedId, actualId);
        }
    }
}
```

The process of doing so however raised some questions about the current design.

If the whole point of creating the abstraction was to hide the implementation details and reduce the tight coupling on the external framework to make things easier to mock and test then having to create an actual `SpreadsheetDocument` and wrapping it for the test seems redundant.

A lot of the parts of the framework are difficult to mock given their internal generation. I would hide those behind other abstractions, but given that I do not know enough about the end goal of this system I cannot advise as to what design structure you should be taking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with your comment about redundancy. Given your test, looks like the `SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper` is redundant and I could test directly on the `ExcelDocument` object loaded in the memory.
I have made a test with using `Moq` and `Verify`. Could you look at that and give your comment on why one over the other https://dotnetfiddle.net/hVHvlM?

Comment: I checked the test and it works. But while the test passes and your verify calls pass the `mockWorksheet` is `null`. My advice would be to try and abstract your interaction with OpenXML parts at a higher level and avoid exposing the parts which seem to be implementation details.

Comment: You are right, the `mockWorksheet` is null. It is verifying method calls only. When you say higher level, what exactly do you mean. Is it something you showed already or this is something different in you have in mind? If this helps, idea for the application is to insert rows into ".xlsx" document and there is no user interface involved, pure backend.

Comment: What I mean is you should simplify the top level of interaction to only deal with the core models like workbook, sheet, row, column and the likes. dealing with parts is an openxml implementation detail that can be hidden behind abstractions.

Comment: Ok, lets say I add method `AddRow` which takes input `SpreadsheetDocument` as parameter and some dictionary for holding data for specific column (thus hiding all the workbook part related implementation). If I want to test `AddRow`, should I try mocking its class or use your proposed open document in memory test approach?

Comment: you can do both. one will be an isolated unit test on the sut while the other would be an integration test with the actual 3rd party object. And again try to hide `SpreadsheetDocument` at the higher levels.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I think I will try to do the higher level abstraction with giving some thought where the cut should be. Also tried to about our 2 test cases, the in memory takes approximately 2x less time (150ms). I guess its due to `Moq` overhead.

Comment: Regards you comment edit about hiding the `SpreadsheetDocument` on higher level. One way would be to use the `filepath` as parameter in the example `AddRow` method. Would that suffice?